# Capture text between two different char. Between the first{ and the last }

Tags: powershell

Capture text between two different char using PowerShell.  Between the first{ and the last } .  Basically there is text with Json in it and I want to capture the json from it.  I have looked for examples but so far no luck.

```
 
PROJECT Description: Azure Test Project Description
 
PROJECT ADMINISTRATORS: jjohnson
 
CONTRIBUTORS: jdoe
 
BOARD PROCESS: Agile
 
SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS:
 
 
{
"organization": "https://dev.azure.com/cloudops",
"projectName": "Test Project",
"projectDescription": "Azure Test Project Description",
"projectProcessType": "Agile",
"specialInstructions": "",
"adminMembers": [
{
"userSamAccountName": "jjohnson",
"userEmailAddress": "jjohnson@test.com",
"userPrincipalName": "jjohnson@test.com",
"projectGroupType": "projectAdministrator"
}
],
"contribMembers": [
{
"userSamAccountName": "jdoe",
"userEmailAddress": "jdoe@test.com",
"userPrincipalName": "jdoe@test.com",
"projectGroupType": "projectContributor"
}
]
}
```

Comment: That will not convert with the non json text in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
[Regex]::Match((Get-Content "sampleinputfile.txt" -Raw),
  '^{.+}',
  [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline -bor
  [Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline).Value
```

Basically this converts the input file to a single (newline-delimited) string (`Get-Content -Raw`), and then uses the [.NET Framework's `Match` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) to do a regular expression match for the lines of text between the `{` and `}` characters (inclusive).

Comment: Yes that worked great.  Could you explain what it does?

Comment: Added basic explanation to answer.

Comment: Thanks Bud!  Super appreciated!  A long time scripter like yourself Batch, VBScript, PowerShell but RegEx has always been something I never dug into.  Thanks again.